# Material-ui how to make the search textfield expandable in material-table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I'm using [material-table](https://material-table.com/#/) and I want to make the search text field expandable like in this [example](https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/#app-bar-with-search-field). But I can't figure out how to change the style for that text field.

[My table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA2xP.png)

I've tried something like this but is not working..

```
options={{
                searchFieldStyle: {
                    padding: theme.spacing(1, 1, 1, 0),
                    // vertical padding + font size from searchIcon
                    paddingLeft: `calc(1em + ${theme.spacing(4)}px)`,
                    transition: theme.transitions.create('width'),
                    width: '100%',
                    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
                        width: '12ch',
                        '&:focus': {
                            width: '20ch',
                        },
                    },
                }
            }}
```

Comment: Also, how can I wrap the title of the table if I'm using the mobile website?

Answer (score 1):

The `searchFieldStyle` parameter is ok inside the `MaterialTable` `options`.

Now due to the fact that you did not supply the whole code I cannot assume that you imported the `theme` correctly in your component. In the future please provide the amount of code for a minimum working variant, adding a working sandbox/fiddle will be better.

The `theme` can be used in a component using the `useTheme` hook from Material-UI read more [HERE](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#usetheme-theme)

```js
import { useTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

....

const theme = useTheme();
```

Now when you pass the style to the searchComponent of the `MaterialTable` you cannot use style and breakPoints as in `JSS` this is inline CSS.

So in order to use media queries you need to use the `useMediaQuery` hook, read more [HERE](https://material-ui.com/components/use-media-query/#usemediaquery)

Also to make the styles based on breaking points it's better if we create a separate variable for the styles.

```js
import useMediaQuery from "@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery";
import { useTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

....

const theme = useTheme();
const smUp = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up("sm"));

let customStyle = {
  padding: theme.spacing(1, 1, 1, 0),
  // vertical padding + font size from searchIcon
  paddingLeft: `calc(1em + ${theme.spacing(4)}px)`,
  transition: theme.transitions.create("width"),
  width: "100%"
};

if (smUp) {
  customStyle = {
    ...customStyle,
    width: "24ch",
    color: "red",
    }
  };
}

...

options={{
    ...
    searchFieldStyle: customStyle,
}}
```

As you can see the breaking point rule `theme.breakpoints.up("sm")` with the `useMediaQuery` and modify the `customStyle` variable.

The one thing that you cannot do is the pseudo `:focus` as React does not support inline css pseudo elements.

Also even if you achieve putting the focus there it will do you no good, due to the fact that the `searchFieldStyle` styles the parent div `class="MuiInputBase-root MuiInput-root MuiInput-underline MuiInputBase-formControl MuiInput-formControl MuiInputBase-adornedStart MuiInputBase-adornedEnd"`. If you focus on the actual input element will no trigger the focus on your Mui-Root container

I've also created a working sandbox that you can check [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-https-tnmq3)

The only viable solution if you want to use transition is to create your own input, override the `<ToolbarComponent>` as shown [HERE](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/component-overriding) in the example. After that create your own filter function for the data and pass it to the table